# How to check whether the image is Portrait or Landscape in Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

Currently, I am working on app which is related to handle pictures. I am modifying the imageview depending on the whether the image is portrait or landscape.

I know I can figure out image is portrait or landscape by comparing the height and width of images.

But the problem I am facing is some images are portrait but the width of image is more than height. Here are those images:

[image1](https://p4.zdusercontent.com/attachment/222168/fHXwLG97dcWp7UESRqzFN3dEK?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..Q_ciQXFpv-0Y-LHc-PmLSg.LAY5tAQBe_RNduMrb7j52A96tCjCkL5L4QOjaupkd4226fRE5VGk6TBoRSnZ0vcXhdGC4wBHyTIEO2OHhjMHnhQajq_duhS6i652cQ2uZhvjdluLun7wIFBo-sf4XP6urrWXZ2FTvw5Dm-dgGR3jd-jL1wNeyz7rqqsOgGj5Glg5ziFJwAnRpT2Cve31DM4wIslZalF01u1LGZaGgka2Dvpnf6dEpjw55JzH1CYxPS7dxn1uToGvMt5H3K99dcMIDXQTOxAqdwIptpu1JiWmjxd9XTmhn55gtpsuYiSWetA.RzVxgONvB2mDrjMEULoToQ)

[image2](https://p4.zdusercontent.com/attachment/222168/JQEoTBhixqy8E89TT85rHwAh3?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..mt1yzWhNXz8vZ5B74giLgA.I5wd9qwvbLsddeSzblRAuIOcXvhDPYw2SPEwrDxNkK3knh5R5-efzNxT8rLra0Ol9GRaq_l3z5x4ABqPTlv_PpHA2_NJNYYRS76EhoRpxxGUBmd2_ugK8s-fDd1Gq2Tnbkvczj_AQZShhEkJ6LPjdGbrqH2ooQPmDQrVtpkEgUNZWNzXhcXX0-7-zjvoxqTnskn7Ev8KCrIyckG-4rS3CjElpNL1zZduiOJplq8d4cD9n2axLv29YAAIni1QabjpMZXghn2heDoJw7mpwl1LCAjJTWDlQ8g1EfHOJAKjX4U.oMrOQj1qiaDUvP1DafHdFA)

Above images are portrait but if you calculate height and width you will find that width is more than height.

***Is there any method in Android which returns whether the image is portrait or landscape?***

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I load a bitmap into the image view, I read the bitmap from the 
file, and then see if the width is bigger than the height.

```
if(bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()){
                //meaning the image is landscape view
                view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, ViewPager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }else{
                view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(250, ViewPager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will return the Orientation & rotation required for your image, which you should be able to use to determine whether the image is portrait or landscape.

```
public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri, String imagePath){
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
        }

        Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
        Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rotate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding question correctly, one approach is to do something like following using `Picasso`

```
            Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    <compare width/height of bitmap to check aspect ratio of image>
                }
```